# Разбиение строки на массив

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Подается на вход строка вида `1223 4567 3214`. Разбиваю строку на массив с помощью `split(" ")`, но в массив входят не только заполненные подстроки, 
но и пустые `"1223"`, `" "`, `"4567"` ,`" "`, `"3214"`.

Как избежать пустых подстрок?

```
String[] mas = textField_1.getText().split(" ");

                    String s1 = new String();
                    for (String s : mas)
                    { 
                        int Menc = Integer.parseInt(s.trim()),
                                d = Integer.parseInt(textField_5.getText()),
                                N = Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText()),
                                Mdec = Exponentiation.ModPow(Menc, d, N);

                        s1 += (char) (Mdec);
                        textField_R.setText(s1);

                    }
```

Comment: Уверены, что во входных данных у вас один пробел между числами?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот этот пример кода с использованием регулярного выражения делает именно то, что нужно:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class A350 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "a   bgg  c";
    String[] mas = s.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++)
        System.out.println(mas[i]);
    System.out.println(mas.length);
}
}
```

вывод:

```
a
bgg
c
3
```

Comment: На самом деле split всегда подразумевает регулярное выражение. Другого split-а без регулярных выражений нет. Так что ответ не в использовании регулярного выражения как такового, а в подборе подходящего под ситуацию.

Comment: @banme ну так-то да. Но единичный пробел крайне редко называют регулярным выражением. При виде "\\s+" может возникнуть вопрос "что это за неведомая ерунда?". Вот я и упомянул, что это регулярное выражение - чтобы было понятно, что гуглить и/или спрашивать далее

Comment: С другой стороны, кто-то видимо не знает, что там должно быть регулярное выражение, вот и суёт пробелы?

Answer (score 3):

Для строк лучше используйте [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split(java.lang.String)) от Apache. Это понятнее и надежнее.

```
StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(null, *, *)               = null
StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("", *, *)                 = []
StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("ab de fg", null, 0)      = ["ab", "de", "fg"]
StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("ab   de fg", null, 0)    = ["ab", "de", "fg"]
StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("ab:cd:ef", ":", 2)       = ["ab", "cd:ef"]
StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("ab-!-cd-!-ef", "-!-", 5) = ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("ab-!-cd-!-ef", "-!-", 2) = ["ab", "cd-!-ef"]
```

Comment: у меня для StringUtils предлагает только метод trimWhitespace и splitString

Comment: StringUtils выглядит удобнее и проще, но не работает "из коробки" - что-то дополнительно надо подключать и настраивать.